# Replacing grep and sed with single awk command

Tags: bash, awk, sed

So I have this line of code that I have been trying to convert to just a single awk command, but have been unsuccessful so far (displays nothing). I am not the most experienced with `awk`, so I am still working on its uses. If someone could give me some guidance and point out what I am doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated. This one-line command will pull a list of all users, and remove all the unnecessary information around it to display just a list of names.

```
ipa group-show ipausers | grep "Member users: | sed "s/,//g" |
sed "s/Member users: //g" | sort
```

I have tried a few different ways, but the latest I have tried is;

```
ipa group-show | awk '/Member users/ { sub ("Member users: ", "") }'
```

This displays nothing...

From my understanding, awk is capable of searching, and removing excess text pretty easily, and would be a solid use case for what I am trying to accomplish. I just have not been able to accomplish what I am trying. Leads me to a couple questions... Is replacing both the `grep` and `sed` an ideal situation for `awk`, or should `grep` and `sed` be used in this case? And what am I doing wrong with `awk` (probably a lot I'm sure haha).

Example text from `ipa group-show`

```
Group name: ipausers
Description: something something
Member users: user1, user2, user3, user4, user5
Member of group: something something
```

I would like to display:

```
user1 user2 user3 user4 user5
```

Comment: You don't print anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
awk -F': ' '/Member users:/{print $2}' file
```

`-F:` splits the line into fields delimited by `:<space>`. Doing so, all user names can be obtained from `$2`.

---

*Update:*

In comments you reminded me that you want to remove the `,` as well. Sorry, missed that. Based on the above command, you can use `gsub()` to replace `,` by space in `$2`.

```
awk -F': ' '/Member users:/{gsub(","," ",$2); print $2}' file
```

Comment: This removes the **Member users:** which is good, but what about removing the commas as well?

Comment: Oh, missed that. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 1):

You could also reduce it to a single (GNU) sed command:

```
$ sed -n '/^Member users: /{s///;s/,//gp}' infile
user1 user2 user3 user4 user5
```

This prevents printing with `-n`, then acts only lines starting with `Member users`, then removes that term (`s///` repeats and removes the last match) and all commas.

A version that (I think – untested) would work with BSD sed (extra semicolon at the end):

```
sed -n '/^Member users: /{s///';'s/,//gp;}' infile
```

Comment: Is there a benefit of using `sed` in this case to `awk`? Great answer though. +1 from me.

Comment: @EdMorton Removed the repeated regex.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably perl it:

```
perl -ne 's/.* users: // && print join " ", split /, /'
```

Strips the leading part of the line, and then 'splits' the rest of the line on `, '

Could add a sort in there easily enough

```
perl -ne 's/.* users: // && print join " ", sort split /, /'
```